# Nest - ElasticSearch.Net - How do I split the FacetFilter hit count returned by a search property

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have a NEST Query;

```
            var desciptor  = new SearchDescriptor<SomePoco>()
             .TrackScores()
             .From(request.Page == 1 ? 0 : (request.Page - 1) * request.PageSize)
             .Size(request.PageSize)
             .MatchAll()
             .FacetFilter("some_name", a => new FilterContainer(new AndFilter { Filters = CreatePocoSearchFilter(request) }))
             .SortDescending("_score");


var results = _client.Search<SomePoco>(x => descriptor);
```

The FacetFilter is returning the total number of HITS from my query. I want to split these hits out using a property on the search request. So, in the search request I have a list of ints. I want to know how many hits were returned for each int in that list.

I hope this makes sense.

I've tried adding a FacetTerm, this gives me the total number of hits for every value of the int query value instead of just the ones that pertain to the search. I understand the query, filter stage, and have tried to change the descriptor accordingly with no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: You are doing a MatchAll(), so what are or where are the list of ints you are searching on? Or do you mean you are retrieving a list of ints and also want to get the number of occurrences of each of those ints?

Comment: The list of ints is the request passed to CreatePocoSearchFilter. I want to get the number of hits that are resultant because of the inclusion of each int in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. My suggestion would be to use a filtered query, and then use a Terms aggregation or facet (facets are deprecated so I recommend moving away from those) on the results.

With an Aggregation:

```
POST /_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": { "match_all": {}},
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "<FIELD_NAME>": [1, 2, 3, 42]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "countOfInts": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "<FIELD_NAME>",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With a Facet:

```
POST /_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": { "match_all": {}},
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "<FIELD_NAME>": [1, 2, 3, 42]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "facets": {
    "countOfInts": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "<FIELD_NAME>",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You could also do the same thing by doing a plain query with `match_all` and then do the filter inside the facet or aggregation. The way I listed it above will perform a little bit better because it will reduce the working set before building the agg/facet.

I did not include the code for NEST because depending on the version of the dlls you are using the format can be somewhat different.